# Differences between CouchDB and Google storage for storing files?

Tags: couchdb, google-cloud-storage

I want to let my customers upload files in my web app.

What are the differences between CouchDB and [Google storage](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/) for storing files?

Answer (score 2):

Several differences:

- Apache CouchDB is written in Erlang
- CouchDB is a document store, it's not optimized for binary data
- It's also locally hosted unless you want a provider like http://www.couchone.com/
- Google Storage is only open to USA developers
- Don't need a Google Account to use CouchDB
- Authentication will probably be provided by Google & by a Google Account, with CouchDB you'll be looking at your own authentication measures

Plus others, like the fact that you can use distributed data & replication very easy with CouchDB.